# Durability of Kinect mounting

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen a number of posts about mounting a Kinect on a robot using either the existing screw holes in the base or a bracket that clips onto the Kinect base.  I'm concerned about the torques that will be applied at the tilting joint on the Kinect when it is mounted in this way.  Has anyone had problems with the joint failing, the tilt motor gears becoming stripped, etc.?  I would like to have the built-in tilting capability of the Kinect available, but if that will end up breaking the Kinect's "neck" I'll remove the base and mount just the sensor housing.  Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10060/durability-of-kinect-mounting/) by [Frank Koss](https://answers.ros.org/users/593/frank-koss/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-05-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bart](https://answers.ros.org/users/286/bart/) on 2011-05-28**:
I used the Kinect base with tilt on top of an inexpensive servo pan/tilt base. No mechanical failures, but the Kinect vertical tilting joint also has a slip joint that allow the panning direction to be set by hand relative to the base. This is annoying but stiff enough not to be a problem.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-05-25**:
For our application, we removed the "base" of the kinect, and screwed directly through the housing.  If you still need tilt, this wouldn't be an option, but the play in the base joint was too much for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The main problem I had was with the stiffness of the link. That's why I created my own design with a dynamixel motor. Designs are available open on my website. The design is so that you also can use it with a Hokuyo. The plates can simple be cut with a desktop laser cutter.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1